# what's the name of this org. compound?

Tags: nomenclature

What's the name of this compound? It is a semi product of Reimer-Tiemann reaction.

**edit**: I think its *Sodium salicylaldehyde*, but i'm not sure.

[image: img]

Comment: You might be interested in reading our [guidelines on how to ask nomenclature questions](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/3120/7951).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's supposed to be the sodium salt of salicylaldehyde, also known as sodium salicylaldehyde, sodium ortho-formylphenolate, 2-hydroxybenzaldehyde sodium salt or sodium 2-formylphenoxide. CAS number: 3116-83-4.

There's actually an error in the structure. The oxygen should have a negative charge if the sodium is written with a positive charge. The salt as a whole is neutral. What's written here is one lone pair, there should be 3 of those and a negative charge.

Comment: thanks, btw there is a negative charge on oxygen in the structure!

Comment: You mean the line above it? That's not a minus sign which it should be, it's too long and to make it clear it should be above and to the right of the atom symbol, just like the plus sign on sodium. What's drawn here is what is usually used for a lone pair, a longer line right above/on the side/below the atom.

Comment: i'm not sure, i used to think that the long line above (mostly oxygen) is a negative charge. this textbook is actually pretty confusing and many-a-times unclear. are you sure that it's used for a lone pair?

Comment: Well yes, that's what they mean but it's just a very, very bad (and in my eyes just plain wrong) way to do it, since you won't be able to differentiate between a negative charge and a lone pair. And yes, that's definitely a lone pair "symbol" which they just abuse as a negative charge for no good reason.

Comment: yeah i checked some other reactions and they put the charges on top of the symbols. imgur.com/a/5EbV8

Comment: The mentioned names (except “sodium salicylaldehyde”) are unambiguous, describe the correct compound and are in accordance with past or present nomenclature rules. However, the preferred IUPAC name according to current recommendations is missing: sodium 2-formylphenolate.